# Why I run out of RAM in Jupyter Notebook using mathplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to save 40.000 figures from pandas dataframe. Altough, I close the figure, I run out of ram:

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
    tmp = X_train.loc[i]
    to_save = pd.DataFrame()
    for letter in range(1,5):
        df = AA.loc[AA["One Letter"] == tmp[letter]]
        to_save = pd.concat([to_save,df])
        
    plt.matshow(to_save.iloc[:,1:], interpolation='none',vmin= 0,vmax=1)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.savefig('D:/CNN/train/df_plot' + str(i) + '.png', bbox_inches = "tight")
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: have you looked at creating `plt.subplots()` inside the loop?

Comment: $JonSG How would you write it in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```